Salesforce Approval Process - Deleted ProcessInstanceWorkitem left records stuck in approval flow
Someone has incorrectly deleted a number of ProcessInstanceWorkitem for account records which were in an approval process. These records Process Instance Step records are now stuck in Pending status and cannot be Approved, rejected or removed from the approval process.
I've tried to restore the delete records via apex and ownbackup but its not possible to restore the records.
I've also tried to re-enter the records in to the approval flow to see if the ProcessInstanceWorkitem would get recreated, but receive a error to say the record is already in a approval flow.
Also cant find/view the records in the Mass Transfer Approval Processes
Are there any other ways I can remove these records from the approval process?
